# Unexpected Output_networking

Tags: java, dns, whois

Here is what I get: 
[image]

And here is my complete code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
class whois {
  public static void main(String args[])throws Exception {
     int c;
     Socket s=new Socket("whois.internic.net",43);
     InputStream in=s.getInputStream();
     OutputStream out=s.getOutputStream();
     String str=(args.length==0 ? "www.osborne.com" : args[0])+"\n";
     byte buf[]=str.getBytes();
     out.write(buf);
     while((c=in.read())!=-1) {
       System.out.print((char)c);
     }
     s.close();
  }
}
```

Now if I go to [this](http://internic.net/whois.html) and type there osborne.com, they will give me information about this domain.
But I am getting a different output.
What is the reason for this? Please explain.

Comment: By the way (for next time), you can copy the text output from your command box and paste it here  - it is then easier readable (and searchable, too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your "www.osborne.com" to "osborne.com".

`osborne.com` is a registered domain which you can search for in whois. `www.osborne.com` is a host, not a domain.

Comment: If you own a domain it's registered in whois, and you can create as many hosts you want using the domain. These hosts are *not* registered in whois - there's no need, since the base domain is.

Comment: Also note that whois isn't DNS. You need to put hosts in DNS, but whois, which keeps ownership information for domains, only cares about "which nameserver handles this domain and all its hosts/subdomains".

Comment: but all the domains are not registered in whois?

Comment: All domains are - but different TLD's (.com, .net, .org, .eu and so on) have different whois servers.

Answer (score 1):

You are typing osborne.com into the whois page, but in your code you are using www.osborne.com. Change your code to use osborne.com instead of www.osborne.com.